# Software recommendation for converting pencil drawings

Tags: software-recommendation, drawing

My staff already use AutoCAD, SketchUp and Illustrator.

I am looking for software to convert simple pencil sketches into drawings. These drawings will later be given to staff for full CAD conversions. Therefore I am looking for a simpler program.

We do custom stone work and use geometric and simple curved designs for floor and wall patterns. Color is not necessary,  only outlines.

Answer (score 4):

I do not know why you want to introduce a fourth application into your workflow.  If you're looking for a solution to convert pencil drawings into vector you can already do this in Illustrator with `Image Trace`. Adobe's documentation and tutorial: [Image Trace in Illustrator — a Tutorial and Guide](http://blogs.adobe.com/adobeillustrator/2013/07/image-trace-in-illustrator-a-tutorial-and-guide.html).

Example:

- new document:

[image]

- drag and drop image on layer:

[image]

- Navigate to `Window -> Image Trace` and the panel will appear:

[image]

Play till you get something but typically you will need to go clean up the anchors which if you're using CAD software you could already be cleaning the anchors in the first place.